# How to deal with products of “shifted” Kronecker deltas?

Tags: linear-algebra, differential-geometry, notation, tensors, index-notation

How does one deal with expressions like
$$
\sum_\mu s_\mu \delta_{2 \mu-1,j} \delta_{2\mu,k} \quad \text{ or } \quad \sum_\mu a_\mu\delta_{2\mu,j} \delta_{2\mu -1,k} \quad ?
$$
The usual rules would tell me set $\mu=\frac{j+1}{2}$ so that the first expression would be equal to
$$
\sum_\mu s_\mu \delta_{2 \mu-1,j} \delta_{2\mu,k} \stackrel{?}{=} s_{\frac{j+1}{2}}\delta_{j+1,k}
$$
but it should be
$$
\sum_\mu s_\mu \delta_{2 \mu-1,j} \delta_{2\mu,k} = s_{(j+1)/2}\delta_{j+1,k}\delta_{j\in \mathbb{O}\
}
$$
where $\mathbb{O}$ here denotes the set of (positive) odd numbers.

So, what are the rules to tackle these problems fast?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key is to keep in mind what the possible indices $\mu$ are in this context. I will assume that in this context, we take $\mu = 1,2,\dots$.

Note that for a given $j,k$, the sum $\sum_{\mu} s_\mu \delta_{2 \mu-1,j} \delta_{2\mu,k}$ can only be non-zero if there exists an **integer** $\mu \geq 0$ such that $2\mu - 1 = j$ and $2 \mu = k$. Note that such a $\mu$ can only exist if $j$ is odd and $k$ is even. Moreover, we can see that if these equations hold, then $j + 1 = (2\mu - 1) + 1 = 2 \mu = k$. Finally, it is clear that if such a $\mu$ exists for any $j,k$, then there is only *one* such $\mu$, which is equal to $(j+1)/2$.

Putting that all together, we find that
\begin{align}
\sum_{\mu} s_\mu \delta_{2 \mu-1,j} \delta_{2\mu,k} &= \delta_{j \in \Bbb O} s_{(j+1)/2}\delta_{j+1,k}.
\end{align}
Assuming that there is no further context here, this seems to contradict both answers that you have given.

Comment: My bad, there was a typo in my question, now fixed. I meant rather, a quick way to do these simplification without going into a “deep” consideration like the one above. I was guessing that $j$ must be odd for $s$ takes only integer subscripts etc.

Comment: @FriendlyLagrangian Well I'd say that the only thing wrong with your initial approach was that you forgot to consider what values the index $\mu$ is allowed to take